# Does the WordPress core software handle bounces on system email?

Tags: email

The WordPress core sends a number of system emails, such as for password changes and for form plugins that use the WordPress core. If any of those emails bounce, does the WordPress core receive and handle them?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: This might be easier if you're using a mail API rather than SMTP, since they often have APIs to check delivery status (using the ID you were given when you sent the email), or can make callbacks to an endpoint on your site with delivery status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer: no. At least not out of the box.

The bouncing email goes to the mail server and if there is no mailbox, catch-all or redirect address set, it will just bounce. You would need to connect WordPress to via pop3 or IMAP to receive emails.

There is at least [one plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-inbox/) for using WordPress as a mail client. I am not sure how it works, so I don't know secure it is and how it (potentially) impacts WordPress performance.